# Listagem de dados com laravel

Tags: php, laravel, lista

Boa noite devs!

Estou precisando de uma força! é o seguinte.

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação usando o framework laravel.

Tenho os seguintes models: projeto e funcionalidade

A regra de negócio da aplicação é a seguinte, cada projeto deve ter uma ou mais funcionalidades
e cada funcionalidade deve pertencer a pelo um projeto, logo tenho o relacionamento 1:n,até ai tudo certo, pois estou conseguindo realizar o cadastro, a edição, a remoção ,e a listagem dos projetos e das suas respectivas funcionalidades.

Porém, criei um link na listagem de projetos chamado funcionalidades, e a ideia
é que quando clicar nesse link (funcionalidades) seja exibido todas as funcionalidades referente a um determinado projeto, por exemplo:

projeto1 (funcionaliade A, funcionalidade B)
projeto2 (funcionaliade c, funcionalidade D)

Porém, é aí que não estou tendo êxito, pois quando clico no link (funcionalidades) é exibido todas as
funcionalidades de todos os projeto e quero que seja exibido apenas as funcionalidades referente a um determinado projeto.

Segue o código que já conseguir desenvolver

```
listagem dos projetos
```

```html
<div class="card">
        <table class="table table-hover">
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>PROJETO</th>
                <th>DESCRIÇÃO</th>
                <th>INICIO</th>
                <th>TÉRMINO</th>
                <th>SITUAÇÃO</th>
                <th>AÇÃO</th>
            </tr>
        @foreach ($listProj as $item)
            <tr>
                <td>{{$item->id_projetos}}</td>
                <td>{{$item->nome_projeto}}</td>
                <td>{{$item->descricao}}</td>
                <td>{{\Carbon\Carbon::parse($item->data_inicio)->format('d/m/Y')}}</td>
                <td>{{\Carbon\Carbon::parse($item->data_fim)->format('d/m/Y')}}</td>
                <td>{{$item->status_projeto}}</td>
                <td>
                    <a href="{{route('listFunc',['id_projetos'=>$item->id_projetos])}}" class="btn btn-sm btn-info">Funcionalidades</a>
                    <a href="{{route('editProj',['id_projetos'=>$item->id_projetos])}}" class="btn btn-sm btn-info">Editar</a>
                    <a href="{{route('delProj',['id_projetos'=>$item->id_projetos])}}"  class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" onclick="return confirm('DESEJA EXCLUIR O PROJETO ?')">Excluir</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
        </table><br>
        {{$listProj->links()}} 
     </div>  


controller funcionalidade

class FuncionalidadeController extends Controller
{
//esse contrutor, tem como proposito redirecionar o usuario para pagina de login, se este não estiver logado e tentar acessar alguma aera do sistema
   
public function __construct(){
    $this->middleware('auth');
}

public function listFunc(){
    $listFunc = Funcionalidade::paginate(5);
    return view('AdminTarefaViews.listFunc',['listFunc'=>$listFunc]);
}



listagem de funcionaliade

<div class="card">
    <table class="table table-hover">
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>FUNCIONALIDADE</th>
            <th>INICIO</th>
            <th>TERMINO</th>
            <th>SITUAÇÃO</th>
            <th>PROJETO</th>
            <th>AÇÃO</th>
        </tr>
    @foreach ($listFunc as $item)
        <tr>
            <td>{{$item->id_funcionalidades}}</td>
            <td>{{$item->nome_funcionalidade}}</td>
            <td>{{\Carbon\Carbon::parse($item->data_inicio)->format('d/m/Y')}}</td>
            <td>{{\Carbon\Carbon::parse($item->data_fim)->format('d/m/Y')}}</td>
            <td>{{$item->status_funcionalidade}}</td>
            <td>{{$item->projeto->nome_projeto}}</td>
            <td>
                <a href="{{route('editFunc',['id_funcionalidades'=>$item->id_funcionalidades])}}" class="btn btn-sm btn-info">Editar</a>
                <a href="{{route('delFunc',['id_funcionalidades'=>$item->id_funcionalidades])}}" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" onclick="return confirm('DESEJA EXCLUIR A TAREFA ?')">Excluir</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
    </table><br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

você tem que usar o id que você passou `$item->id_projetos` como parâmetro para sua lista

```
public function listFunc($id_projetos){
    $listFunc = Funcionalidade::where('id_projeto', $id_projetos)->paginate(5);
    return view('AdminTarefaViews.listFunc',['listFunc'=>$listFunc]);
}
```